# Filter data set based on values in string column

Tags: c#, dataset, filtering

I am getting a data set from an Oracle SELECT query that contains, among other things, a list of user IDs and corresponding list of "Active" flag (0/1).

For instance:

```
ds.Tables[0]["UserIDList"]: (11, 14, 56)

ds.Tables[0]["ActiveFlag"]: (0, 1, 0)
```

I need to be able filter out user IDs 11 and 56 and only keep 14. So I can end up with:

```
ds.Tables[0]["UserIDList"]: (14)
```

It would be easy to filter out based on a column using DataTable.Select or Linq but not sure how to tacke this one.

I normally include code for what I have tried when posting questions but in this case I have no clue how to proceed! So at the risk of getting downvoted for not including code ...

Comment: I don't understand this comment: *"It would be easy to filter out based on a column using DataTable.Select or Linq"*. Does that mean you're looking for a non-Linq answer?

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns? I don't recognize `(11, 14, 56)` as a type.

Comment: Yes, Linq would be fine. I just meant if I was just filtering out by a column that had single value, it would have been easy. Like filter by start date.

Comment: The data returned is an Oracle aggragte (LISTAGG (vpm.UserID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY vpm.UserID)). It returns '11, 14, 56'. Similarly for ActiveFlag.

Comment: Try : ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("UserIDList") == "abc").CopyToDataTable();

Comment: No, can't. I don't know what user IDs I am filtering, I need to filter by their corresponding active flag value. If corresponding active flag is 1, keep user ID; if it is zero remove it.

Comment: If we forget about the data set and just think of two arrays, would it be easier to come up with a solution? I can store user id list and active flag in two arrays and work on those and then assign the resulting user id list (where only active user ids are present).